# Getting current time in seconds and saving it in integer

Tags: java, android

In Android,  I am getting the current time in milli seconds as follows:

```
long currentDateMS = new Date().getTime();
```

and the value is right when I print the time.  But I need the time in seconds and save the time as an integer.  I am converting it into seconds as below

```
int seconds = (int) (currentDateMS / 1000);
```

but then it shows the wrong time. I think there is an overflow while converting but I do not know how to solve it.

I need to convert it into 4 bytes of time data

Comment: You cant. You will wrong time when you convert. long is the milliseconds representation of the current time. To convert the time from miliseconds to seconds, you need to multiply . not divide.

Comment: `currentDateMS` is already in milliseconds. Your `miliseconds` is actually seconds

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `getting the current time in milli seconds`? What you're getting in the line you posted is the timestamp, which is *milliseconds since epoch start*, rather than (what I assume you want) *milliseconds since day start*.

Comment: current time in seconds is `1423075116`. MAX_INT is `2147483647`. No overflow here.

Comment: `then it shows the wrong time` how do you figure that?

Comment: @njzk2 What if the OP's system time is set to the value > `MAX_INT` ?

Comment: @OP, what time it is showing you ? and what is your current system time ?  please remember that `getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` represented by your date.

Answer (score 2):

You will get a wrong answer if the value of your milliseconds rolls over the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is `2,147,483,647`

for instance, `System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` results in `2147483647`
while `System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE+1);` gives `-2147483648`.

Also, instead of using `new Date.getTime()` you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a long variable uses 62 bits to store its value while an int uses only 32... this conversion makes you lose a lot of information gives a wrong answer. Is there any special reason to use an integer instead of a long?

If you just want to know the time difference between 2 moments you may use congruences to know the skipped time.

If you knew (for instance) that two operations will take less than an hour (3600 seconds) to complete and want to know the time difference between them, you could use something like:

```cpp
int time1 = (int)((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)%3600);
int time2 = (int)((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)%3600);
int difference = (3600 + time2 - time1)%3600;
```

Comment: Since when do longs use such an odd number of bits?

Comment: Yes I need it as an integer as I need to send 2 bytes of data.

Comment: `I need to send 2 bytes of data.` you do realize integers are 4 bytes, right?

Comment: my bad, longs use 64 bits :S sorry